# The best approach to find combinations in link-3 games

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, game-development

What approach is the best for detecting combinations in link-3 games, where you need to tap on some group of blocks and it disappears? What is the best way to detect this groups?
Is it better to detect them at start or the moment of click on group?
[image]

Comment: Best means what?

Comment: @stark commonly used and effective